# OpenOCD Symbol Lookup error: undefined symbol libusb_handle_events_timeout_compleeted

Tags: compiling

I tried installing [openocd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/openocd.1.html) with [apt get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-get.8.html) in Ubuntu 18.04.4.
as in

> sudo apt install openocd

When I try calling openocd from the terminal it fails with

> openocd: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/openocd: undefined symbol: libusb_error_name

Then I tried to build it from [source](https://repo.or.cz/w/openocd.git) - no problem compiled fine. 
But the source compiled version fails with this error:

> openocd: symbol lookup error: openocd: undefined symbol: libusb_handle_events_timeout_completed

Any ideas please?

I've got libusb-1.0.0-dev installed along with [hidapi](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/hidapi)

I assume the symbols required by openocd are included in the libusb package - so I don't know why it can't find them.

output of

```
ldd /usr/bin/openocd | grep local
```

is

```
libusb-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f3995949000)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, yeah my mistake - have added the release info. It's easy to overlook these things!

Comment: Please click [edit] and add tthe exact command you used to install _openocd_ to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please also tell us what you meant by _etc_ after hidapi -- what other packages specfic to this issue were installed. It's tough to troubleshoot without seeing your system, so we must ask in a very precise way. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Please add output of `ldd /usr/bin/openocd | grep local` to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove self-compiled USB-library by

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libusb*
```

and then OpenOCD should work.